# Is the tension force (instead of normal force) the apparent weight here?

Tags: weight

[image]

[According to this link](https://www.physics.utoronto.ca/%7Ejharlow/teaching/everyday06/reading02.pdf),

> An object's weight, henceforth called "actual weight", is the downward
> force exerted upon it by the earth's gravity. By contrast, an object's
> apparent weight is the upward force (the normal force, or reaction
> force), typically transmitted through the ground, that opposes gravity
> and prevents a supported object from falling.

In my picture, the elevator is accelerating upwards with an acceleration $a$. An object is attached to the ceiling of the elevator with a massless string. The actual weight of the object is $mg$. No normal force exists here, so can we say that the apparent weight of the object is the tension force $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*. . . . . so can we say that the apparent weight of the object is the tension force $T$?*  - Yes

Imagine that the string was a massless spring balance.
The reading on the spring balance, which is the apparent weight of the object, would be the same as that of the tension on the string.

Using $F=ma$ with "up" as the positive direction $t-mg = ma \Rightarrow T = Mg+Ma$ and that is the apparent weight of the object.

If $a=0$ then $T=mg$ which is the weight of the object.

If $a=-g$, ie the system is in free fall, $T=0$ and so the onject appears to be weightless ie the reading on a spring balance would be zero.